# Error Creating Table "Missing Right Parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, parentheses

I keep being told I am missing a right parenthesis but I'm not seeing it, can anybody point it out?

```
CREATE TABLE Member
( MEMBER_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, FIRST_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL
, LAST_NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL
, STREET_ADDRESS varchar(255) NOT NULL
, CITY varchar(255) NOT NULL
, STATE varchar(2) NOT NULL
, ZIPCODE int NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID)
);
```

Comment: Can you give the exact error message? And is this the ONLY command that you're running?

Comment: Works copied and pasted as-is for me... odd. Is this the SQL statement as-is or is there code or variables being used?

Comment: @Jazzepi that's seriously the error message it gives me, no line reference or anything. I'm using APEX so it's just: "Missing Right Parenthesis"

Comment: Oracle apparently does not have AUTO_INCREMENT columns.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116209/auto-increment-column-differences-in-sql-syntax-between-oracle-and-mysql for work-arounds.

Comment: @WingTangWong - 
Did the statement work for you in **Oracle**?

Comment: @PM77-1 'doh. Tested in mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as AUTO_INCREMENT in oracle.

Take a look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle). It's likely this that is giving you the error.

Comment: Crap... Auto_Increment is MYSQL >.>